# running cmd from visual studio 2008 /c#

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and am trying to run a cmd line utility called mediainfo from a c# script. I am trying to redirect the execution results output to a text file (file1out.txt) and when running straight from the cmd console the following works: 
`C:\programs\mediainfo_cli\mediainfo.exe --Inform=file://C:\temp\template.txt "C:\temp\3gp\file1.3gp" > c:\temp\3gp\file1out.txt`

However, from the script it doesn't work.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LaunchCommandLineApp();
    }

    static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
    {
        // Use ProcessStartInfo class
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        string strArg = @" --Inform=file://C:\temp\template.txt C:\temp\3gp\file1.3gp > C:\temp\3gp\file1out.txt";

        //startInfo.FileName = "calc.exe";
        startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Programs\\mediainfo_cli\\mediainfo.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = strArg;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        try
        {
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }

        catch
             {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The redirection operator (>) is a feature of the Windows command processor. You aren't actually invoking the command processor with Process.Start (unless you start "cmd.exe"). To use stdio redirection, you must read it from the StandardOutput stream. Here's an example that shows how to do it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

You've almost got it!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do redirection like that. Cmd.exe handles seeing the "> file.txt" and sets up the redirection before executing the process.

Remove the "> file.txt" from strArg. After starting the process you need to read the StandardOutput stream and write the data to the file. There is a simple example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx